# Webpage crashes when loading jQuery DataTable - too many rows?

Tags: php, postgresql, datatables

I'm working on a management system website that consists of tables of data pulled from a Postgres database that is running on a server. I have been retrieving the data by writing PHP queries and echoing out the rows of data from the database. This works for all of the pages on my website, except for one that is attempting to retrieve data from a table with over 50,000 records - when I attempt to load that page, it either times out or crashes my browser completely. When viewing the data from this table using pgAdmin, it takes around 10-20 seconds.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, or how I could go about speeding up the load time of my datatable? Thank you!

**Edit**:

This is how I'm querying the database using PHP:

```
$query = "SELECT respondentid, pro, homephone, otherphone, fname, lname, note from respondent";
$result = pg_query($query);
echo "<table id='respondents'>";
echo "<thead> <tr> <th>Headings</th> </tr></thead>";

while($row = pg_fetch_array( $result )) {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $row['columnnames'] . '</td>';
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
```

Here are the database columns:

```
respondentid serial not null,
pro character varying(3),
homephone character varying(15),
otherphone character varying(15),
fname character varying(15),
lname character varying(20),
note text
```

Comment: Could you post your error messages in logs, your query, your table structures and the explain plan of your query?

Comment: Have you tried to do a [LIMIT Query Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html) ? E.g. `LIMIT 50`

Comment: @Arkhena Edited my post with some more details. I'm not sure about error messages in logs as my page just hangs there for ages and I'm not sure what to look for.

Comment: @joe-black I want all of the records to be loaded in the table as the main use for the table will be the search, and I need to be able to search all records.

Comment: @ellenmichellen Ok. Please, check my answer.

Comment: dataTables will get beyond most browsers script execution limit apx. around 4-5.000 rows. If you need to handle more rows than that, you should consider [**serverSide processing**](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). It is not an error or because dataTables is slow, it is really optimized on the clientside code - any JS code or jQuery, angular, ember whatever will fail to handle 5.000 table rows, populate it with sorting, filtering, customised rendering, events and so on within default browser execution time limits.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve all the rows from the table with this quick workaround:

- wrap the code with `while` loop,
- add `ORDER BY` clause to the query,
- select only a few rows with `LIMIT` clause.

.

```
echo "<table id='respondents'>";
echo "<thead> <tr> <th>Headings</th> </tr></thead>";

$rows_total_result = pg_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM respondent');
$rows_total_row = pg_fetch_row($rows_total_result);
$rows_total = $rows_total_row[0];

$offset = 0;
$row_count = 1000;

while (($offset + $row_count) <= $rows_total) {

    $query = "SELECT respondentid, pro, homephone, otherphone, fname, lname, note "
           . "from respondent ORDER BY respondentid "
           . "LIMIT {$row_count} OFFSET {$offset}";
    $result = pg_query($query);

    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['columnnames'] . '</td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    $offset += $row_count;
}

echo "</table>";
```

Though, this won't solve the problem of browser crashing, because of the huge data size and possibly long execution time.

The common solution is to implement a pagination to browse big table.

- [Five ways to paginate in Postgres, from the basic to the exotic](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/)

Comment: When I tried this, I received the error message "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" and the table stopped loading, and did not look like a datatable.

Comment: Yes, I've just edited my answer to explain this issue. Please check it.